# Syntax for an expression to calculate subtraction using variables

Tags: google-app-maker

Want to calculate the years left on a lease

In plain English the calc is:

```
Var today = the current Year (eg. 2019)
Var year = the current record LeaseYear (eg. 1995)
Var term = the current record LeaseTerm (eg. 125)
```

So that:

left = term-(today-year)

or

left = 125-(2019-1995)

I am at the learning stage when i appreciate what i need to do (either using an expression in the binding area of the page field, or calling a script) but I am not very good with the syntax.

Would really appreciate a pointer here where I can then do more complicated things with this lesson.

Thanks

Comment: So what do you need? A function to return the result? Or a simple variable to save the result? ...

Comment: Oh yeah.. Don't use capital letters for `var`. ;)

Comment: thanks for the 'var' point - yeah I would like a function - just to show the layout

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Do you need the result rendered in your html? Or do you need a function to calculate the result for multiple situations?

Answer (score 0):

As a **function expression**:

```js
var calc = function(term, today, year) {
  return term - (today - year);
};

var result = calc(125, 2019, 1995);

// Let's render it to HTML
var htmlElement = document.getElementById("some-id");
htmlElement.innerText = result;
```

```css
#some-id {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>Solution: <span id="some-id"></span></p>
```

As a **function declaration**:

```js
function calc(term, today, year) {
  return term - (today - year);
};

var result = calc(125, 2019, 1995);

// Let's render it to HTML
var htmlElement = document.getElementById("some-id");
htmlElement.innerText = result;
```

```css
#some-id {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>Solution: <span id="some-id"></span></p>
```

As an **arrow function (ES6)**:

```js
const calc = (term, today, year) => term - (today - year);

const result = calc(125, 2019, 1995);

// Let's render it to HTML
const htmlElement = document.getElementById("some-id");
htmlElement.innerText = result;
```

```css
#some-id {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>Solution: <span id="some-id"></span></p>
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: I really appreciate your time and help. This will be handy for sure as I will need to display HTML results at some point - but what I am looking for (sorry for bad question) is a function that I can paste into a Client Script that I call from a Page Widget.

So the function would use a calculate the current year from the browser or server, and i'd want to bring in the parameters from the current datasource ie. the year field and the term field to do the maths - then return the answer - i just dont know how to write that code syntax

Comment: Ok. I changed the answer. This is what you're looking for?

Comment: that's awesome - helps so much - really appreciate your effort and help

Comment: My pleasure. Glad to help. Please mark my answer as solution and +1. :)

Comment: I voted but it won't show as I have less than 15 reputation points. Ps. I'm about to buy a chromebook to develop AppMaker while on holiday. I've noticed that even on my i7 64gb desktop, chrome crashes with 3 appmaker apps open and a few other tab - since my app got bigger. Is it possible to develop appmaker on a chromebook? 16gb minimum? Any thoughts.

Comment: No experience there but I wouldn't recommend it. As I understand it, a chromebook is intented for browsing and does not have much capabilities. I suggest you ask this question in a new topic. ;)